# NetworkX k_clique_communities(G,k,clique=None) generator object error message

Tags: python

I am trying to find all communities defined graph by using  k_clique_communities function from NetworkX.
Now, Python throws out no error message but the following statement:

<generator object k_clique_communities at 0x0000000009A82BC8>

Comment: You have to provide more details. How are you trying to find, what is your program look like, which statement is giving you the above output?

Comment: could you show us some code? please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask